# Primefaces values from p:dialog do not update p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

When I try to add values to p:dataTable using p:dialog, the values are not added to the table (not even update the bean).

The xhtml file is

```
<h:form>
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Goal" widgetVar="goalDlg"
    resizable="false" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)" >
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel value="Minute:" />
            <p:inputText value="#{matchBean.minute}" immediate="true" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Is self:" />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{matchBean.self}" immediate="true" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="OK" action="#{matchBean.addTheGoal}" />
        </f:facet>
</p:dialog>

    <h1>Add Match Players</h1>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:dataTable value="#{matchBean.homePlayers}" var="homePlayer" >
            <f:facet name="header">
            #{matchBean.homeGroupName}
            </f:facet>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Play</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Player Name</f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{homePlayer.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Start</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Yellow</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Red</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Rep</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Min</f:facet>
                <p:inputText />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Goals</f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{homePlayer.yield}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{matchBean.addGoal(homePlayer, true)}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:dataTable value="#{matchBean.guestPlayers}" var="guestPlayer">
            <f:facet name="header">
    #{matchBean.guestGroupName}
    </f:facet>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Play</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Player Name</f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{guestPlayer.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Start</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Yellow</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Red</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Rep</f:facet>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Min</f:facet>
                <p:inputText />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Goals</f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{guestPlayer.yield}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{matchBean.addGoal(guestPlayer, false)}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

and relevant code from the managed bean:

```
        @ManagedBean
        @SessionScoped
        public class MatchBean {
    ...
        private int currPlayerId = 0;
        private boolean isHomeGroup = false;
        public void addGoal(MatchPlayer player, Boolean isHomeGroup) {
            currPlayerId = player.getId();
            this.isHomeGroup = isHomeGroup;

            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('goalDlg').show();");
        }

        public void addTheGoal() {
            MatchPlayer[] players = null;
            if (isHomeGroup) {
                players = homePlayers;
            } else {
                players = guestPlayers;
            }
            for (MatchPlayer player : players) {
                if (player.getId() == currPlayerId) {
                    MatchGoal goal = new MatchGoal(minute, self);
                    player.addGoal(goal);
                    System.out.println("Goal added at minute " + minute + ", self = " + self);
                    break;
                }
            }

            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('goalDlg').hide();");
        }
...
    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        System.out.println("Setting minute to " + minute);
        this.minute = minute;
    }
```

and MatchPlayer:

```
    package com.ransh.soccer.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MatchPlayer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private boolean played;
    private String name;
    private boolean started;
    private boolean yellowCard;
    private boolean redCard;
    private boolean replaced;
    private int minute;
    private List<MatchGoal> matchGoals = null;

    /**
     * C'tor
     */
    public MatchPlayer(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        played = false;
        started = false;
        yellowCard = false;
        redCard = false;
        replaced = false;
        minute = 0;
        matchGoals = new ArrayList<MatchGoal>();
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the played
     */
    public boolean isPlayed() {
        return played;
    }

    /**
     * @param played the played to set
     */
    public void setPlayed(boolean played) {
        this.played = played;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the started
     */
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    /**
     * @param started the started to set
     */
    public void setStarted(boolean started) {
        this.started = started;
    }

    /**
     * @return the yellowCard
     */
    public boolean isYellowCard() {
        return yellowCard;
    }

    /**
     * @param yellowCard the yellowCard to set
     */
    public void setYellowCard(boolean yellowCard) {
        this.yellowCard = yellowCard;
    }

    /**
     * @return the redCard
     */
    public boolean isRedCard() {
        return redCard;
    }

    /**
     * @param redCard the redCard to set
     */
    public void setRedCard(boolean redCard) {
        this.redCard = redCard;
    }

    /**
     * @return the replaced
     */
    public boolean isReplaced() {
        return replaced;
    }

    /**
     * @param replaced the replaced to set
     */
    public void setReplaced(boolean replaced) {
        this.replaced = replaced;
    }

    /**
     * @return the minute
     */
    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    /**
     * @param minute the minute to set
     */
    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    public void addGoal(MatchGoal goal) {
        matchGoals.add(goal);
    }

    public List<MatchGoal> getGoals() {
        return matchGoals;
    }

    public String getYield() {
        if (matchGoals.size() == 0) {
            return "No Goals";
        }

        StringBuilder yield = new StringBuilder();
        for (MatchGoal goal : matchGoals) {
            if (yield.length() > 0) {
                yield.append(", ");
            }
            if (goal.isSelf()) {
                yield.append("S(" + goal.getMinute() + ")");
            } else {
                yield.append(goal.getMinute());
            }
        }
        return yield.toString();
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems with this code:
1. setMinute() is not called at all.
2. homePlayer.yield and guestPlayer.yield are never updated.
How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `immediate="true"` from form components in the dialog. Also, remove `appendTo="@(body)` from the dialog, or add a `<h:form>` in it. Since you are appending the dialog to the body, it gets out of `<h:form>` of your page. You can check this if you inspect the DOM in your browser.

Comment: I tried. It didn't help. Still setMinute() is not called.

Comment: OK, when I removed appendTo=, setMinute() is called, but still homePlayer.yield is not changed (it displays "No Goals". Any idea?

Comment: Try to add `id` to the panel grid surrounding your data tables like `<p:panelGrid columns="2" id="pgPlayers">`, and add `update="pgPlayers"` to your command button. I assume all of the java code works as expected, goals are added to players as they should be? Interesting application, btw :)

Comment: OK, it's working now. You saved me hours (if not days) of debugging. And in the java code I also had small problem which I fixed. Thank you!